# how to read a pcap file in c++ to get the packet information?

Tags: c++, pcap

I want to write a program in c++ to read a pcap file and get the information of packets , like len,sourc ip, flags and etc. now I found the code like below and I think it will help me to get the information, but I have some questions:
at the first I want to know which library should I add to my program and after that what is pcap_next,and how can I get the handle from a pcap file?

```
/* Grab a packet */
packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
if (packet == NULL) {   /* End of file */
    break;
}
printf ("Got a packet with length of [%d] \n",
        header.len);
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to link your application with [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/). To get a handle, you should use [`pcap_open_offline`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html). [`pcap_next`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html) reads the next packet from the handle.

Comment: thanks for your useful links,I have another question.which other information of packet can I get by "header",and how?for example can I write 'header.source ip' or 'header.flag' ?

Comment: @user3210586: I don't know. I only knew that those functions were from libpcap and briefly looked at the manual pages. You might be able to find what you're looking for if you look through them yourself more thoroughly.