# Modifying a pcap file based on packet length and other parameters

Tags: pcap

I agree that there are a lot of posts to do with editing .pcap files on this site. However, I haven't been able to find a .pcap editor that can effectively remove entries based on certain specific conditions.

For example, say I want to remove all packets of length 172 bytes after Time = 2 seconds. Is there a tool that provides this level of flexibility?

If not, is there a way I can access the .pcap file using C++ and then edit it, and save it back as a .pcap file?

Comment: I recently wrote a Java tool based on Pcap4J for this purpose: https://github.com/jvmk/pcap-trimmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**

The most flexible approach is writing your own code for that kind of stuff. Reading a pcap file is fairy straightforward in most programming languages using dedicated libraries. In C++ it can be done using [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214148/how-to-read-a-pcap-file-in-c-to-get-the-packet-information))

**Solution #2**

If the pcap file isn't too big, you could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). Just load the file into Wireshark, and type in the following display filter, followed by `Enter`: `!(frame.time_relative > 2  && frame.len == 172)`. Then go to `File` -> `Export Specified Packets..` and pick `displayed`, enter a file name, and save the result:

[image]

**Solution #3**

If the file size is large, but not huge, or if you need a command line solution, you can use [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), the command line version of Wireshark. Just read in the original file (`-r`), apply the same display filter (`-Y`), and write the resulting file to a new location (`-w`):

Something like:

`tshark -r input.pcap -Y "!(frame.time_relative > 2  && frame.len == 172)" -w output.pcap`

**Solution #4**

The last solution I can suggest is using [libtrace](https://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php) ([github here](https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace)).
However, it's a bit tricky since you need to filter on both packet properties as well as time.

One way would be using the following sequence of steps:

1. first split your pcap file using [tracesplit](https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace/wiki/tracesplit) into two files - A.pcap and B.pcap where A.pcap will contain packets until the 2 second mark, and B will contain the rest of the trace.
2. Use [tracefilter](https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace/wiki/tracefilter) to filter A.pcap so only packets that aren't 172 bytes long will remain - the filter string is `len != 172`
3. Use [tracemerge](https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace/wiki/tracemerge) to merge both the filtered A.pcap and B.pcap into a single file.