# can i edit the packet length the of a already existing .pcap file

Tags: packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I want to add Laplacian noise of scale 1, to the packet lengths using Scapy or any tool.I am doing a my M.tech project in contextual privacy

I wanted to add noise but my pcap file is not editable(interpreter says). As i was running Scapy in python

Comment: Hi, this might be irrelevant or relevant but you should explore here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294004/modifying-a-pcap-file-based-on-packet-length-and-other-parameters, Also Welcome to StackOverflow! Add more details in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add Laplacian noise of scale 1, to the packet lengths

It's certainly *possible* to do that, but it *must* be done by reading packets from the file and writing out a *different* file - you can't modify the file in place, as the captured packet length is also used to calculate the *record* length, and modifying it in a packet will make all subsequent packets unreadable.

A loop (in pseudocode) of

```
while (read_a_packet(input_file))
    calculate difference between on-the-network length and captured length
    apply noise to the captured length
    set the on-the-network length to the sum of the new captured length and the difference from above
    if (the new captured length > the original captured length)
        pad the packet with {noise, zeroes, ones, 0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef, whatever else you want}
    write out the modified packet to the output file
```

I think there are APIs in Scapy that would let you write a loop of that type.